# How to draw multiple shapes

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a program with OpenGL that creates two rectangles, but my problem is that when I create my two model_views, the first one gets overwritten by the second one so only one rectangle is displaying and I'm not sure how to display both. I posted the entire code. How do I get both triangles to render?

```
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"
#include "glm\glm.hpp"
#include "glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };

GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];
GLuint location;

const GLuint NumVertices = 4;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Setting up our pipeline and preparing to draw 
void init(void)
{
//Defining the name of our shader files
ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
    { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
    { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
    { GL_NONE, NULL }
};

//Loading and attaching shaders to our pipeline
GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
glUseProgram(program);  //My Pipeline is set up

// Coordinates of vertices (Square)
GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
    { -0.3, -0.45 }, 
    { 0.3, -0.45 },
    { 0.3, 0.45 },
    { -0.3, 0.45 }

};

// Colors for vertices in {R, G, B} mode
GLfloat colorData[NumVertices][3] = {
    { 1,0,0 }, //Red
    { 0,1,0 }, //Green
    { 0,0,1 }, //Blue
    { 1,1,1 }  //White
};

glGenBuffers(2, Buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colorData), colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "vertexColor");
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model_matrix");

}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//This is done by using glutDisplayFunc function. Look at the main method
void drawScene(void)
{
//Clear the screen and preparing to draw
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/////////THIS IS WERE I CREATE RECTANGLES
//Sun
glm::mat4 model_view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

model_view = glm::scale(model_view, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0)); //shrink it 

glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view[0][0]);

glm::mat4 model_view2 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0));

model_view2 = glm::scale(model_view2, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0)); //shrink it

glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view2[0][0]);

//The following function passes the generated rotation function into the vertex-shader  

//Starting the pipeline
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, NumVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, NumVertices);

//Flush the image onto the window (screen)
glFlush();
}

//The registration happens in the main() function using 
glutIdleFunc(runEveryFrame) function.
void runEveryFrame()
{
//Increasing our rotation angle
rotate_value += 0.001;

glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//Initializing to draw
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
glewInit(); 

//init function is defined above
init();

//Registering the display function
glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);

//Registering the idle function
glutIdleFunc(runEveryFrame);

//glutMainLoop enters the event processing loop
glutMainLoop();



}
```

Comment: Order matters. You can't just set one matrix after the other, then draw two quads and expect the two draw calls to use two different matrices.

Comment: Move one of `glDrawArrays` call between the two `glUniformMatrix4fv` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You call glDrawArrays with the same arguments, without changing any uniform between the two calls. My bet would that the two shapes are drawed, one over the other.

You'd have to call `glUniformXXX` before each `glDrawArrays` calls, if the uniform data (the model/view matrices) have changed :

```
void drawScene(void) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //first draw call with model/view transformation 1
    glm::mat4 model_view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    model_view = glm::scale(model_view, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0)); //shrink it 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, NumVertices);

    //second draw call with model/view transformation 2
    glm::mat4 model_view2 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0));
    model_view2 = glm::scale(model_view2, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view2[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, NumVertices);


    //Flush the image onto the window (screen)
    glFlush();
}
```